# Are explicit strings in C# .NET more efficient to the framework?

Tags: c#, .net

In some programming languages all strings have an @ prefix i.e. var foo = @"this is a test";

If a string does not have an @ prefix does the .NET framework have to do extra work?  Is there any scanning that has to be done?  I'm curious of we should be using @ on all strings possible?

Comment: A side note: If there's no difference, then you SHOULDN'T use @ liberally, as it'd be pointless visual clutter.

Comment: No difference, just syntax sugar. Make sense to use when it helps to avoid a lot of escaping or to suppress annoying Resharper's localization warnings as Jon said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using verbatim strings may or may not be faster by an amount which you likely won't even be able to measure by feeding the compiler specially crafted programs. In any case this processing happens at compile time, which makes all of the associated work "free". So from that point of view there's absolutely no argument either for or against verbatim strings.

That said, I have seen development tools consider non-verbatim strings as candidates for localization -- in which case using a verbatim string where appropriate does have some value.

Comment: I wouldn't even speak of (negligible) extra work. If I'm not mistaken, it just means a different part of the lexer consumes the string literal. And since lexers are typically finite automata, the length of the string should dictate the performance, not which token is matched.

Comment: @delnan: Well, theoretically I guess the two flavors of strings would be different tokens, in which case the lexer might have more `if (nextChar == something)` tests to do in the non-verbatim case. It's kind of absurd to talk about performance there (especially since there's also the non-string-literal part to lex) but I didn't want to use "absurd" in the answer. :)

Comment: I agree, but making wild guesses at performance is awfully tempting. Any such guess would have to assume a lot about the implementation anyway. So let's just leave it at "it may or may not be faster by an amount which you likely won't be able to even measure with pathological inputs".

Answer (score 8):

From a point of view of MSIL there is no difference

```
string test = @"\test1";
string test2 = "test2";


IL_0001:  ldstr       "\test1"
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldstr       "test2"
IL_000C:  stloc.1
```